# Local storage local site security

Tags: security, local

I have a local webpage hosted on my computer (all files stored locally) that I'm debating putting sensitive information into its localstorage.  Is this secure if you're doing it locally like this?  It's just made up of javascript, html and css....no communication with other servers.  Thanks.

Comment: "Secure"? Secure against what? Maybe it helps if you tell us what kind of sensitive data it is, and what the html site is doing with it.

Comment: deviantfan.  It will be used for financial purposes for a friend.  Entering in financial data.  Secure against others being able to see the numbers.  Thanks.